# File Specific cache http header for IIS 6

Tags: http, cache, iis-6, http-headers

Is there a way to set cache related header for a specific file type in II6?  We want to turn off cache on all our *.js and *.css file here, but IIS6 is forcing us to do a all or nothing approach.

Answer (score 2):

For each folder containing the files you want to cache, open it's properties page, and under the HTTP Headers tab, set expiration date to something like 2050-12-31

Comment: If you want to disable cache (which the OP does), you need to set the expiry to a date less than today (say, yesterday, or 1990 or something)

Answer (score 1):

You can set caching for individual files in IIS6 by right-clicking the file in the Content pane, going to Properties and setting the cache settings, or as rodiaz suggested, doing it to an entire folder.